# Problem with emulator after new ADT update

Tags: android, emulation, adt

After updating to ADT 12, at first it seemed ok, then I got some problems like these:

Emulator runs improperly and gives the problem I report below.

I tried to use the quick code from XML windows and it mingles the codeline. Has anyone encountered the same problems?

This is the error I got in the console after trying to run a project:

```
[2011-07-14 20:28:36 - cursoMC5leccion6] ------------------------------
[2011-07-14 20:28:36 - cursoMC5leccion6] Android Launch!
[2011-07-14 20:28:36 - cursoMC5leccion6] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-14 20:28:36 - cursoMC5leccion6] Performing com.wocmultimedia.cursoMC5leccion6.Main activity launch
[2011-07-14 20:28:36 - cursoMC5leccion6] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'avdGooglemarket'
[2011-07-14 20:28:36 - cursoMC5leccion6] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avdGooglemarket'
[2011-07-14 20:28:42 - cursoMC5leccion6] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-07-14 20:28:42 - cursoMC5leccion6] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-07-14 20:29:57 - cursoMC5leccion6] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.wocmultimedia.cursoMC5leccion6.Main activity launch'!
[2011-07-14 20:33:22 - cursoMC5leccion6] ------------------------------
[2011-07-14 20:33:22 - cursoMC5leccion6] Android Launch!
[2011-07-14 20:33:22 - cursoMC5leccion6] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-14 20:33:22 - cursoMC5leccion6] Performing com.wocmultimedia.cursoMC5leccion6.Main activity launch
[2011-07-14 20:33:22 - cursoMC5leccion6] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'avdGooglemarket'
[2011-07-14 20:33:22 - cursoMC5leccion6] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avdGooglemarket'
[2011-07-14 20:33:24 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2011-07-14 20:33:24 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Documents and Settings\Angelo Giammarresi\.android\avd\avdGooglemarket.avd/sdcard.img
[2011-07-14 20:33:24 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2011-07-14 20:33:24 - cursoMC5leccion6] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2011-07-14 20:33:24 - cursoMC5leccion6] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Answer (score 6):

Delete all the "*.lock" dirs in your AVD directory, i.e. [...]/.android/avd/[youravd].avd

Answer (score 3):

You will sometimes also need to delete snapshots.img

Path to AVD folders on Windows 7 is:

C:\ Users \ (YourUsername) \ .android \ avd \ (YourAVDsName.avd) \

Answer (score 2):

Delete userdata and sdcard image files from avd folder.That will fix this error for me

Comment: I made different attempt and I assumed that is a problem of this 2.2 google api issue cause this happen only with this kind of AVD. If I create a different API based AVD it runs with no problem. I use to run it till appears in red in the console that launch has been canceled, then I close the emulator and run it again so it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To clear the "already in use" problem without losing the state of your AVD, the specific files you need to delete are the "pid" files in the .lock directories under YourAVDName.avd. I did this while the AVD was not running, but I didn't test it without closing the AVD, so I don't know for certain if that is necessary (though it seems logical.)

Answer (score 1):

clear your eclipse AVD (delete data with *.lock files)

Answer (score 0):

The AVD locks some resources to be able to run. Clear your .lock directories, the AVD might have not closed properly which resulted into the resources being still locked, AVD unlocks the resources by simply deleting the .lock directories, you can do that manually by deleting the .lock directories.